# ionic 4 modal controller dialog doesn't work

Tags: angular, ionic4, modalviewcontroller

l used modal Controller dialog for [for Ionic 4](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)  to get parameters from another page . i did coding in correct way and when l click on button to launching a modal Controller he doesn't show . even i  added model page in declarations and entryComponents but unfortunately same problem

[image: ssss]

You can see there in image console log he bring data parameters from another already without execute button to do that . he look like present modal controller automatic .

code for  modal controller

```
 async addWeather(){

    const AddWeatherModal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AddPagePage,

    });
    await AddWeatherModal.present()
    await  AddWeatherModal.onDidDismiss().then((r) => {

          if(r.data.result){
            this.getWeather(r.data.result)
             console.log(r)
          }else if (r.data.result ==""){
            this.AlertNotSelected()

            console.log("No Data . ")
          }


    });

  }
```

html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button autoHide="true"></ion-menu-button>

    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button (click)="addWeather()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="search"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title text-center>محطات الرصد الجوي</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>



</ion-header>

<ion-content >

</ion-content>
```

any help please?

Comment: Did you import AddPagePageModule in app.module.ts?

Comment: l imported `AddPagePage` in HomePageModule in `declarations` and `entryComponents`

Comment: l tried now , same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l found problem , the problem is with `global scss`

most be add this line in global scss

```
.modal {
display: flex !important;
}
```

Styles of bootstrap 4 have the definition of modal class and turns display to none by default . now he is working fine .

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
const AddWeatherModal = this.modalController.create({
      component: AddPagePage,

    });
AddWeatherModal.then((modal) => modal.present());
```